# Integrated Graphics causing lock ups

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xubuntu, 16.04, intel-graphics

I have a MSI GS60 Ghost Pro 4k with an intel 6700 hq and a nvidia gtx 970m with xubuntu and windows 10 dual booted. I have nvidia prime set up and when I'm running the 970m everything works flawlessly in ubuntu. When I try and use the integrated graphics so that I don't burn through all of my battery the system locks up entirely whenever the integrated graphics card would be used. This includes the obvious such as running many applications, but also happens during installation of certain packages and when running commands like lspci or sometimes when switching between GPUs.

Comment: how do you have configured your BIOS Setup in this laptop in the graphics part ?

Comment: I don't have a graphics part of my bios, I have my boot mode set to UEFI with fast boot disabled, intel speedstep on, intel virtualization technology on, and everything else disabled. I couldn't find anything to do with the integrated graphics in BIOS.

Comment: which Ubuntu version do you install ? which version of nvidia-prime package ? which version of nvidia graphics driver? it was a  .deb package ?

Comment: I'm running xubuntu 16.04, nvidia 361.45 installed through apt, and whatever the latest version of nvidia-prime. Nothing involving graphics was installed through a .deb package. Nvidia-prime works as expected, although I crash when switching to integrated graphics. And like I said in the original post, I only ever crash when running the integrated graphics card, never when on the 970m.